# How to close Android webview modal?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I am working on an app that is a wrapped web app with a separate modal webview created dynamically for certain urls. I am using this library for the modal webview:

https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android

I would like to programmatically close the modal but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
fwv = new FinestWebView.Builder(getActivity())
    .setWebViewListener(new WebViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(String url) {
            super.onPageStarted(url);

            if (url == "blah blah") {
                // close modal
            }
        }
    });

fwv.show(url);
```

This is inside of a fragment for the main webview.

Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

check this from it's doc:

WebView Listener Options

```
setWebViewListener(WebViewListener listener);
addWebViewListener(WebViewListener listener);
removeWebViewListener(WebViewListener listener);
```